# How to use a case or decode as part of an analytical window function in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, analytic-functions

I would like to do something like this:

```
select sum(nvl(total_time_out, 0)),
       sum(nvl((case when day_of_week = 'Mon' then total_time_out else 0 end) over (partition by person_id), 0))
from   xxpay_tna_summary_v
where  person_id = 7926
```

where the second column only returns the sum of the total time out hours for the Monday. Is this possible in Oracle SQL, and what is the correct syntax?

Comment: You have to give more details if some one is to work this out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/df376/2

```
select sum((case when person_id = 100 then total_time_out else 0 end)) total_time,
   sum(nvl((case when day_of_week = 'MON' then total_time_out else 0 end), 0)) monday_time
from   xxpay_tna_summary_v
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is invalid, because sum belongs to over, but you moved the sum keyword to the beginning of the expression. Here is the corrected statement:

```
select nvl(sum(total_time_out), 0),
       nvl(sum(case when day_of_week = 'Mon' then total_time_out else 0 end) over (partition by person_id), 0)
from   xxpay_tna_summary_v
where  person_id = 7926;
```

(I also changed places for sum and nvl in your first expression. It does the same but might be nanoseconds faster, because nvl has to be applied just once.)

Comment: This will probably fail with `not a single-group group function`, since the first SUM is aggregate function.

Comment: Your select fails with not a single-group group function.